# DB issue in rails? Rails query and SQL query return different results (default_scope's fault?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise

We have over 29K users in our database. "User" is one of our tables and has a unique field "email" with an index defined in one of our migrations:

```
#3434324_devise_create_user.rb

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :email, :null => false, :default => ""
    end
    add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
  end
end
```

We don't have any issues creating users... for the most part. However, with some emails **(potentially those that have been previously deleted from the DB at one point or where created long time ago)**, we are encountering a rare issue:

**We can't create them because the "unique" validation fails**, however, there is not a single user with that email.

This is an example of what is happening (which does not make any sense if you ask me).

When we try to create a user with the email "example@example.com":

```
$ p = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
$ User.create!({email: "example@example.com", password: p})
```

We get the following result:

```
(11.6ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (11.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'example@example.com' LIMIT 1
(10.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
  from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@example/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
```

At the same time, if we look for that email in the database:

```
$ User.find_by_email("example@example.com")
```

It does not exist!

```
User Load (12.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."disabled" = 'f' AND "users"."email" = 'example@example.com' LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

Does this make sense for any of you?

Comment: creating through sql cmd ?

Comment: Try to re-index for `email` if you don't have any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Nithin: this is what we get with a sql SELECT:

    `result = @connection.exec_query("SELECT  1 AS one FROM users  WHERE users.email = 'example@example.com’ LIMIT 1")
  SQL (12.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM users  WHERE users.email = ‘example@ example.com’ LIMIT 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x00000107dc6330 @columns=["one"], @rows=[["1"]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={"one"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Integer:0x00000107a23340>}>`

It says that there is a row with that email but the same does not happen using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @BhanuPrakash: would you recommend `https://github.com/ankane/searchkick` to reindex the `email` field?

Comment: or perhaps a simple `@connection.exec_query("REINDEX TABLE users;")`?

Comment: @raulsan I would prefer doing the former to keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you for your response @BhanuPrakash. I just did a `result = @connection.exec_query("REINDEX INDEX index_users_on_email;")`

and after that nothing has changed. We still get the same error. However, an important clue is that the following sql statement: 

`result = @connection.exec_query("SELECT  * FROM users  WHERE users.email = 'example@example.com' LIMIT 1")`
returns the user with ID 3245..... Only SQL queries can find this user, but it is invisible to ActiveRecord. I am not sure why this is happening yet.

Comment: I have tried both `https://github.com/ankane/searchkick` and `@connection.exec_query("REINDEX TABLE users;")` but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between the query you get when you run `User.find_by_email` and the one that is run by the validation: the former has an extra condition on the `disabled` column. It would seem that when you've been deleting using you've just be flagging them as deleted rather than actually removing.

Given what you've posted I can't tell where that is coming from (perhaps a default scope or an extension to rails) but it would certainly account for the difference in results. You could confirm this by searching for the user in the psql shell.

You could change the validation to ignore these disabled rows:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, conditions: -> { where(disabled: false) }
```

However you still wouldn't be able to create this user since the unique index on email would prevent this. If you want to able to have multiple users with the same email (but only one that is not disabled) you would have to make this a multi column index on email and some other attribute that would be different for all the "old" users but would be the same for active users

Comment: You are absolutely right Frederick. There was a default_scope defined long time ago in the user model (`default_scope { where(disabled: false) }`) and we had forgotten about it. Thank you so much for your help Frederick. You have saved us many hours of being in front of the screen. Very much appreciated (note that I have changed the title of the question to make it more accessible to other readers in the future).